# SQLintersects query not working properly

Tags: mysql, geospatial, spatial, point-in-polygon

I am trying to select the points which lies in a specific polygon from my table.
Here my Table test1 have data4 column of geometry type and it contains:

```
2,3  
5,6  
7,10
```

When I am trying the following query its returning empty row. Please help me to resolve the error.

```
DECLARE @g geometry;   
SET @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 4 0, 4 4, 0 4, 0 0))', 0);  
SELECT        *  
FROM            test1  
WHERE data4.STIntersects(@g) = 1;
```

I have also tried:

```
WHERE @g.STContains(geometry::STGeomFromText(test1.data4, 0))='True'
```

This didn't work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really talking about MySQL as your question is tagged, you're using the entirely wrong methods. STGeomFromText is an SQL Server function.

The [MySQL query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html) that does what you want is as simple as;

```
SELECT * 
FROM test1 
WHERE MBRContains(GeomFromText('Polygon((0 0,0 4,4 4,4 0,0 0))'), data4)
```

[An SQLfiddle for testing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/957754/1)

Just as a bonus, here is how to write it for SQL Server;

```
SELECT * 
FROM test1 
WHERE geometry::STGeomFromText('Polygon((0 0,0 4,4 4,4 0,0 0))',0)
          .STContains(data4) = 1
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/771e8/6).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was writing for the SQL  Server function